# Can I simplify DNSSEC implementation in a context of public content?

Tags: dnssec

Contents of [government gazette](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Government_gazette), Linux distributions,  Open Data, etc. are public, there are no constraints for "increase user privacy". On the contrary, we want to guarantee transparency... But all tutorials and explanations about DNSSEC are also about internet banking and user privacy: is possible to separate concerns? Is possible to **simplify the DNSSEC installation/infrastructure** when we need only to enhance **public data** transference? 
(on HTTP, HTTPS, FTP or SFTP downloads and hash integrity confirmations)

The aim of DNSSEC here is **only** to avoid [Man-in-the-middle attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack).

Comment: Why? What exactly do you gain from not offering confidentiality?

Comment: @MechMK1 We gain **simplicity**, we reduce development and maintenance costs, etc. And with simplicity we also reduce the [transaction costs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transaction_cost) for (infrastructure and bureaucracy) fiscalization.

Comment: I disagree. Having to create a custom implementation that only gives you one thing instead of using something ready-made adds complexity and increases development costs. DNSSEC offers both Confidentiality and Integrity out-of-the-box - just use it.

Comment: @MechMK1, I agree in part, because this is the question: **where** the "ready-made DNSSEC light"? it exists?

Comment: What makes you so adamant about using a "light" version? Why not use the thing that already exists and that works for everybody?

Answer (score 3):

DNSSec does not encrypt traffic, i.e. it is not about privacy at all. DNSSec is only to provide authenticity of the DNS responses. This is done by the authority (domain owner) signing the records. This signature prevent tampering by a man in the middle or replacement by a DNS hijacking ISP or similar. Thus, there is no need for an additional DNSSec-light since DNSSec is already what you propose as DNSSec-light.

I'm not sure where the claims about privacy come from, but I suspect that this got confused with DNS over HTTPS (DoH), DNS over TLS (DoT) or DNSCurve. All of these encrypt the DNS traffic, but DNSSec does not.